# How to get column like results to single string with separator

Tags: teradata

I have a silly problem which I'm not able to solve in Teradata.

I have n tables and for each of n tables (n>1000) I have to get the table's columns, which can differ from table to table.

My question is: how can I get the result from one query (something like `Select columnName from dbc.columns where tablename = table1`) in a string, let's say `_vColumns`, in order to be able to use later on the value in that sorting (`_vColumns`) in a dynamical SQL syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did that [long ago](http://teradataforum.com/teradata/20060710_173415.htm)  using `dbc.columns`

```
 /*** Rows to concatenated string ***/
 /*** Nested version instead of hundreds of CASEs.
       Returns a single concatenated string consisting of up to 2048
 columnnames ***/
SELECT
  databasename
 ,tablename
 ,max(case when rnk mod 16 = 0 then ColumnName else '' end) ||
  max(case when rnk mod 16 = 1 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
  max(case when rnk mod 16 = 2 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
  max(case when rnk mod 16 = 3 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
  max(case when rnk mod 16 = 4 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
  max(case when rnk mod 16 = 5 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
  max(case when rnk mod 16 = 6 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
  max(case when rnk mod 16 = 7 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end)
 as Columns
from
 (
  sel
    databasename
   ,tablename
   ,rnk / 16 as rnk
   ,max(case when rnk mod 16 = 0 then ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 1 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 2 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 3 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 4 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 5 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 6 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 7 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 8 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 9 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 10 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 11 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 12 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 13 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 14 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
    max(case when rnk mod 16 = 15 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) as ColumnName
  from
   (
    select
      databasename
     ,tablename
     ,rnk / 16 as rnk
     ,max(case when rnk mod 16 = 0 then ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 1 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 2 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 3 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 4 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 5 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 6 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 7 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 8 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 9 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 10 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 11 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 12 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 13 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 14 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) ||
      max(case when rnk mod 16 = 15 then ',' || ColumnName else '' end) as ColumnName
    from
     (
      select
        databasename
       ,tablename
       ,trim(columnName) as ColumnName
       ,rank() over (partition by databasename, tablename
                     order by columnid) -1 as rnk
      from
        dbc.columns 
     ) dt
    group by 1,2,3 
   )dt
  group by 1,2,3
 )dt
group by 1,2
```

But, since Td14.10 you should use dbc.Column**V** instead (if you got any column name longer than 30 characters) and then 2048*128 characters will hit the maximum limit of 64000 characters...

Comment: Hello dnoeth, I ran what you have wrote, but I am not sure what it is; sorry but I'm not very familiar with Teradata. What I mean is can I use the value from "Columns" as the value for a local string variable? Now I have the text "Columns001.txt" as the value for Columns field from your statement  and when I click the "Column001.txt" I can see its content, but somehow as being a file...Many thanks

Comment: @BogdanM: That's a setting in SQL Assistant `Tools - Options - Data Format - Handle Varchar columns as CLOB if size >`,  change to 64000 and  SQLA displays it inline...